# Read from socket freeze

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I have problem while reading data from client on server. The read() function will always freeze (block) after all data are readed and waiting for more data what is undesirable for me.

Server program:

```
   soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); 
   struct sockaddr_in sin;  
   sin.sin_family = AF_INET;  
   sin.sin_port = htons(port);   
   sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
   bind(soc, (struct sockaddr*) &sin, sizeof(sin));

   if (listen(soc, MAX))
      return;

   int socc;               // socket for clinet     
   while (1) {
      if ((socc = accept(soc, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sinlen)) < 0)
         break;
      while ((result = read(socc, pointer, SIZE)) > 0) {
         // after the data are readed, read function will block
      }
      // do some stuff and write reply to client => will never done
   }
```

Client program:

```
   ...
   soc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)  
   struct sockaddr_in socketAddr;
   socketAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   socketAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
   memcpy(&(socketAddr.sin_addr), host->h_addr, host->h_length);
   if (connect(soc, (sockaddr *)&socketAddr, sizeof(socketAddr)) == -1)  
      return;
   if (write(soc, req.c_str(), strlen(req.c_str())) < 0)
      return;
```

The main problem is that I don't know how much data will be client sending to server, so the server should read all data from socket and after nothing is coming, leave the reading cycle. But the server read whole message for example (30 bytes) and waiting for more (but no more is coming). The sockets are still opened because the client is waiting for reply from server.

Comment: Do you know *if* the client will be sending data to the server? And have you considered a `select()` loop rather than a blocking IO call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make your socket non-blocking. The read will immediately exit in that case if there is nothing to be read with a specific error.

Look at [C- Unix Sockets - Non-blocking read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107271/c-unix-sockets-non-blocking-read)

Answer (score 2):

As stated earlier use non blocking or add RCV_TIMEOUT to socket.

```
struct timeval tv;

tv.tv_sec = 30;  /* 30 Secs Timeout */

setsockopt(sockid, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,(struct timeval *)&tv,sizeof(struct timeval));
```

Comment: In my case, this solution is way better, because the select command results in a huge slowdown when I try to send a file of about 30MB. Simply adding your code after the socket creation statement did the trick.