# Read function isn't returning any value

Tags: c, sockets

Value of `n` coming 9, `sockfd = 3` and as it calls the read function, it was not coming out of the read function. After printing read start line, it stops there only:

```
while(1)
{
        if (n < 0)  
            {
                printf("ERROR writing to socket");              
            }   
        else if(n == 0)
            {
                printf("Nothing");

            }
            printf(" read start n=%d\n ,sockfd = %d\n",n,sockfd);
            n = read(sockfd,buffer,1024);

        if (n < 0)
            {   error("ERROR reading from socket");
            }
            printf("Reply= %s",buffer);
            write_buf_to_file("/root/abc_regr/receive.txt",buffer);  
}
return;
```

Comment: Are you sure there is data waiting?  Try using `recv()` instead of `read()` and pass `flags=MSG_DONTWAIT` to get non-blocking receive.  Then it will return immediately if there is no data available to read.

Comment: That's gruesome formatting of the code.  It also seems odd to be detecting write errors before you have written anything (with the tests of `n` preceding the code to `read`, and when it is `read`, not `write`, that is setting `n`).

Comment: "value of n coming 9, sockfd =3 and as it calls the read function, it was not coming out of the read function"  What??

Comment: john @ i use recv(). Now it is giving error- ERROR reading from socket: Resource temporarily unavailable. so what does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

`read()` is by default blocking call, so it will wait till it gets the data. If you want non-blocking function read answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8107271/744616) question.

Comment: Can you explain more, It's a blocking call, ie the process is suspended until the data is ready at input, i've written a c program with read(2) and give an input from a file like this `cat file | ./my_c_prog` but the program never responded, i've put printf after the read call to check if it's returned but nothing have shown up? how to fix this?